List of symbols using an alternative to lstdoc
Last year I found this question and I used the code provided in the answer to typeset a list of symbols for my bsc thesis; the code as presented in said question is the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstdoc,longtable,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\symbollist{}

\def\newsymbol#1#2#3{\label{symbol#1}#2\long\expandafter\gdef\csname createNewSymbol#1\endcsname{$#2$ & & #3 & & \pageref{symbol#1}\\}\lst@AddTo\symbollist{createNewSymbol#1,}}

\def\PrintListOfSymbols{%
\lst@BubbleSort{\symbollist}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1} 
\begin{longtable}{r p{.01\textwidth} p{.8\textwidth} p{.01\textwidth} l}
\@for \i:=\symbollist\do{%
    \csname\i\endcsname }
\end{longtable}
}

\section{Contents}
Here the integers $\newsymbol{Z}{\mathbb{Z}}{integers}$ appear first. Here the continuous functions $\newsymbol{CX}{C(X)}{continuous functions on $X$}$\newpage

Here the other symbols appear first: $\newsymbol{R}{\mathbb{R}}{real numbers}, \newsymbol{N}{\mathbb{N}}{natural numbers}$

\begin{center} Even entries $\newsymbol{Q}{\mathbb{Q}}{rational numbers}$ from inside an environment appear.  \end{center}

\section{List of Symbols}
\PrintListOfSymbols

\makeatother
\end{document}

I've been typesetting my msc dissertation (I am using the gsm-l class from AMS) and I would like to use the same code for the list of symbols. However, I noticed that the packagelstdoc does not work well with the definitions of \subsection given in the file gsm-l.cls, e.g. after starting a subsection the whole text format (after such subsection) becomes \bfseries. I solved this problem removing the lstdoc package.
After that I tried to use showexpl in the same code as an alternative to the lstdoc package but the output is 
and I get the error:
\PrintListOfSymbols ->\lst@BubbleSort 
                                      {\symbollist } \renewcommand *{\arrays...
l.2 \PrintListOfSymbols
                       
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

I would like to if there is an alternative to lstdoc that could be used with the same code for the list of symbols.
